# "to bite *back*"?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

How do you say "to do something *back*" in Japanese?

For example, I read on the internet that if a horse bites you the best thing to do is "to bite back".

> How would you say "to bite back" in Japanese?

Of course, this construction is universal in that you can "do anything back" basically. Another example would be "to kiss someone back".

> Is there a general construction for "to do X back" in Japanese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general construction is ～返{かえ}す.

Let me list an example:

to bite back = 噛{かみ}付{つ}き返{かえ}す

Remember, however, this construction has a negative connotation.

In the case of "to kiss someone back" I would say キスのお返しをする.

Comment: Thank you again for another excellent answer! One question: what about 噛み返す？Does it mean anything? And if so, why is it  噛付き返す and not 噛み返す?

Comment: 噛む could mean both "chew" and "bite". If you say a dog 「噛む」 then it might well be "bite", but in most cases you should explicitly say 「噛みつく」 for biting. @eltonjohn I think "vying" is more accurate than "negative", for expressions like 一点を取り返してやった are undoubtedly "positive".

Comment: @ broccoli forest: < "vying" is more accurate than "negative"> I agree in this case. <一点を取り返してやった are undoubtedly "positive"> I suspect that depends on the viewpoint. If you got it back for someone, then that someone must be grateful for you, thus it sure is positive for him/her. But for the one who suffered the "revenge", it is hardly positive (so I guess.) Oh I forgot, ～返す often indicates "tit for tat."

Comment: So if I was a native speaker and the horse bit me and I bit back would I use 噛付き返す or 噛返す because it's clear that it's bite and not chew in this case?

Comment: @user213845: If the horse bit you in a friendly manner, then 噛返す may work, but otherwise I would use 噛付き返す.

Comment: It was definitely not friendly, I have a large red bruise on my thigh and it was quite painful ^^

Comment: @user213845:  Just a warning in case you aren't aware, the 〜返す construct is also used to mean repeat/do again (繰り返す).  Context should make the meaning clear.

Comment: This reminds me of Judo and counter-throws, such as [大外返](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRffdB64hMw)

Comment: @istrasci Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @user213845 Yes, at least I think I speak Japanese natively while I'm wide awake :D

Comment: 「噛み返す」でもいいやん。eg「噛まれたら、噛み返してやれ！」By the way, it's normally spelled 噛**み**付く, 噛**み**返す, rather than 嚙付く, 嚙返す, no?

Comment: this construction has a negative connotation. >> How about あいさつし返す、会釈し返す? Are these just a few of rare exceptions?

Comment: @hoko: <あいさつし返す、会釈し返す?> I have never heard those usages. I would say あいさつを返す、会釈を返す.

Comment: はあ。。。また関西弁ていうんでしょ。。。「微笑み返す」「笑い返す」 would be a few of rare exceptions, right?

Comment: @broccoliforest :-D

Comment: @Choko: <噛み付く, 噛み返す, rather than 嚙付く, 嚙返す, no?> I am not sure, but probably "本則" and "許容" of this -> http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/okurikana/honbun06.html apply here. The document writes "読み間違えるおそれのない場合は", but unfortunately it is not documented who is responsible to judge whether certain usage is considered as "読み間違えるおそれのない" or otherwise.

Comment: 「かみかえす」と打っても、私のパソコンでは、「噛返す」という候補は出てこないですね。。。ま、私のパソコンがしょぼいからかもしれませんが。